# Biometric API - How to force to use Face authentication?

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I want to force a device with face id, to use Face authentication to login in my application, using Biometric API.

I'm using BIOMETRIC_WEAK but, its always asking for fingerprint instead face id.

```
 BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder().apply {
        setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK)
        setTitle(activity.getString(title))
        setDescription(activity.getString(description))
        setConfirmationRequired(true)
        setNegativeButtonText(activity.getString(cancelTitle))
    }.build()
```

Looking for which devices has BIOMETRIC_STRONG (Class 3), I have found only Pixel 4.

So people with Samsumgs and whatever cannot use Face authentication inside apps?

Comment: "I'm using BIOMETRIC_WEAK but, its always asking for fingerprint instead face id" -- it is going to ask for whatever the user configured for device authentication. If somehow the user configured both face and fingerprint, I would not be surprised if the device chose to use the stronger one, which in this case would be fingerprint. "So people with Samsumgs and whatever cannot use Face authentication inside apps?" -- are you saying that you set up a device with face authentication and without fingerprint authentication, and `BIOMETRIC_WEAK` does not use face authentication?

Comment: @CommonsWare yep, without any fingerprint registered, face auth its not showing.